# retrieve rows in order from oracle table

Tags: java, oracle

I'm inserting data from excel into oracle table and i want to retrieve records in same order. Below is my code. Can anyone help?? Thanks in advance.

```
        ResultSetMetaData rm = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = rm.getColumnCount();
        String colunmName  = rm.getColumnName(columnCount);

        if (rs != null && rs.first()) {
            do {
                bw.write(rs.getString((rm.getColumnName(columnCount))));
                bw.write("|");
                bw.newLine();

            } while (rs.next());
        }
```

Comment: Rows in a table don't have any intrinsic order. Are you storing a column value that represents the order they were created, e.g. a sequence or a timestamp set by the insert or a trigger? (Which may still not be 100% reliable, particularly if you're inserting in parallel)

Comment: I dont know Java but from oracle point of view, there is no 'order' among rows. If your table has a unique key and you are inserting based on that, then while selecting you can use `order by` in SQL to retrieve it. Try inserting some rows in table and select. You will never get it in the same order as you inserted.

Comment: @Utsav I would be reluctant to use the word `never` in any setting.  He _might_ get the records in the order in which he inserted them, although this is doubtful and there is no guarantee of this whatsoever.  Yes, he should a column if he wants to sort the records.

Comment: Completely agree with you. Thats what I meant. Poor choice of word from my side.

Comment: Earlier when i tried using rs.next(), i was getting result but first row was garbage value. so i change it to above code.. Does it hampering results??Also, i don't want a sorted data .. i just want data as it is from table. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve rows in insertion order, you need to define the ordering.  Unlike arrays or files in other languages, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Hence, there is no ordering.

So, how can you do what you want?  Well, you can include an identity/serial/auto-increment column in the table.  This column is incremented as the rows are inserted into the table, and should retain the original ordering.

In Oracle 12c, this would be a column defined like this:

```
tableId number generated always as identity,
 . . . .
```

In earlier versions of Oracle, you can do the same thing using a sequence and trigger.

Oracle is a bit late in making this functionality easy to implement.  Most other databases have supported these types of columns for many yearas.